# Save sent email from Salesforce into user's 'Sent Items' mailbox in Gmail

Tags: lightning-for-gmail

I have come across a requirement where I would be sending emails to specific recipients ( who are non- salesforce users ) .Once the sender sends email ( which is done through a lightning component and using sendEmail() functionality ) , the sent email needs to be saved in the sender's mailbox in the Sent Items.I surfed over the internet looking for a solution similar to the requirements I have but noluck yet.I have heard about Gmail to Salesforce but not sure about vice-versa.

Any leads in the right direction would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

The Gmail "Sent" mailbox is more or less magic. You cannot, strictly speaking, control what appears there, because every user may have different configurations or filters.

However, BCCing a Gmail user on a message that goes out from a Salesforce user whose email address is that Gmail address *does* result it it appearing in Sent Mail *as well as their inbox*, with default settings:

[image]

Note this email was sent from Salesforce to a Contact with a different email address than the sender, with a BCC to the sender. It appears in both the Sent and Inbox folders in Gmail, for the account that matches my Salesforce user account's email address.

Your Lightning component can specify the user's own email address as a BCC, which will result it in showing in Sent for the corresponding Gmail user. The user would have to create a filter on the Gmail side to prevent such messages from showing as new messages in their Inbox, however - you have no control over that.

Edit: It looks like you're encountering issues with Gmail's security infrastructure. Unfortunately, that's too deep in mail-server admin for my knowledge. Whether or not it's possible to fix *may* depend on whether you're using Google Apps or not - I'll have to defer to anyone who has better knowledge of technologies like DKIM/SPF.

Comment: Thanks for the detailed response.Just wanted to know what settings/config work do I have to do to make this work?

Comment: No config required. Just make sure the user's own address is BCCed using `SingleEmailMessage.setBccAddresses(bccAddresses)`.

Comment: Awesome.Thanks a lot for pointing this out.Just wanted to confirm once again that I don't need to set up anything like Lightning Gmail or Gmail to Salesforce? All i need to do is set the user's gmail address in Bcc ( user record will also have gmail email address)  and once email is sent, it will automatically show in the Sent mail ?

Comment: That is correct. But as above, it will also show in their inbox unless you configure a filter on the Gmail side.

Comment: Hey David, I tried your approach.It worked the first time but after that every time I send the mail, i receive the mail with this displayed in the body:====

This may be a spoofed message. The message claims to have been sent from your account, but Gmail couldn’t verify the actual source. Avoid clicking links or replying with sensitive information, unless you are sure you actually sent this message.====

the mail does not go to my 'Send Items' folder.Any idea why it worked the first and how to make it work seamlessly?